# uninstall key value is the same for the product on all systems

Tags: windows, windows-installer, registry, installation, registrykey

I am installing a product on my machine (64bit windows 7), and have installed it on Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2012, and all the systems have the same uninstall registry key. Is it a universal that a product will have the same uninstall key irrespective of the Windows version? Or does the product install shield define the GUID/key?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you refer to a key such as this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{020CDFE0-C127-4047-B571-37C82396B662}
```

The value between the bracers ({...}) is just the ProductCode property of the installer. Hence the uninstall key is fixed, no matter which OS version you are installing on.

If you work with InstallShield, it is defined in the 'General Information' section. Note that InstallShield sometimes (depending on project type) adds another uninstall key, InstallShield_{...}, under the 32-bit registry hive.